# Track changes with Git using already-changed files and a pristine copy

Tags: git

I was given a project with files like so:

```
MyProject/
  a.txt
  b.txt
  c.txt
```

I initialized a Git repo in the directory, but (foolishly) did not add all files to the repo at the start. Instead, I added files to the repo right before I realized I'd need to change them.

```
git add a.txt; git commit -m "Pristine A"
<awesome changes to a.txt>
git commit -am "Awesome Changes"
```

Unfortunately, in my fervor of mad edits I forgot to do this for some files. (Read: tens of files in many directories, which are going to be hard to find by explicit path.)

```
<awesome changes to b.txt>
git status # Uh oh, new file b.txt
```

I can get a snapshot of the project before my awesome changes, so that Git can tell me which files have changed since then. However, I don't want to lose the tens of commits (with descriptions) that I already added.

**How can I take the "pristine" snapshot, and have Git calculate which files have changed compared to my working directory, without losing my existing commits and without getting false positives for those files that did change but that are already recorded in commits?**

*FWIW my original "justification" for not adding the entire directory at the start was because there are thousands of files unrelated to my work, the directory is only available over high-latency SMB, and I **thought** that I knew which files were important.*

Comment: @vergenzt Yes, all in the master branch.

Comment: Also, just to clarify, is this accurate: Your current repo shows `b.txt` and `c.txt` as having been "created" in later commits, but you want it to show them as having been created (as the pristine copies that you have) in the initial commit, and the following commits just changing them?  **Edit:** Never mind, I think I understand your question now.

Comment: @vergenzt To be clear, the repo currently shows `b.txt` and `c.txt` as untracked files. I don't care when it shows them as being added to the repo, but I need `b.txt` to be added in one comment and then have another commit showing the diff between the pristine and my changes.

Comment: How do you want the final repo to look?  Do you want to insert a commit that adds the "pristine" copy of `<file>.txt` before the first commit in which that file is modified (if there isn't one already)?  Or do you want it to seem like they were there from the beginning?  **Edit after your comment:** k.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your pristine snapshot and create a new git repository with it (add all the files and commit them).

In your current repository, do

```
git remote add pristine /path/to/pristine/repository
```

afterwards

```
git remote update pristine
```

You now can reference the master of the pristine repository in `git diff`

```
git diff pristine/master
```

to see a complete diff between your working directory and the pristine commit. If you only need the changeset, `--summary` should be the option you are looking for. The [git diff](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-diff) man pages detail all other switches.

This should result in a changeset where already added files are mentioned differently than already modified but not added files.

What you do with that afterwards is up to you, however it should be possible to take the pristine commit and using rebase, put it at the beginning of the tree, adding every file, replaying every commit afterwards.

Comment: If you do `git remote update pristine` to fetch the pristine repo, you can then use `pristine/master` to refer to it's master branch rather than having to scribble down the hash somewhere: might make the process a bit simpler and robust.